# Write-Verbose output that doesn't wrap to command width in Powershell

Tags: logging, powershell, word-wrap

I'd like to `Write-Verbose` a lot of data to an out file. Here's how I'm doing it.

```
Start-Transcript -Path $TargetDir\RunUnitTests.log -Width 1000000
Write-Verbose "five million character lines and stuff"
```

This works great, except that the output is auto wrapped to the standard width of a console, this makes the log look absolutely terrible.

I found a solution here<sup>dead link removed</sup>
, but it's so involved and complicated that I don't want to just throw this in my script below a comment `#Thar be dragons`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For the related problem of prevent wrapping in _all_ verbose output, not just from explicit calls to `Write-Verbose`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41504786/45375).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very simple workaround based on `Write-Host` which does not have such a problem. In the beginning of the session install/dot-source the replacement of the default `Write-Verbose`:

```
function global:Write-Verbose
(
    [string]
    $Message
)
{
    # check $VerbosePreference variable
    if ($VerbosePreference -ne 'SilentlyContinue') {
        # do this via Write-Host
        Write-Host "VERBOSE: $Message" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow'
    }
}
```

Then this works as needed:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
Start-Transcript -Path .\RunUnitTests.log
Write-Verbose ("verbose writes five million character lines and stuff. " * 20)
```

That is: it takes into account `$VerbosePreference`, it writes to host in yellow, transcript output is not wrapped and it is still marked VERBOSE.

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20101105055855
**********************
Transcript started, output file is .\RunUnitTests.log
VERBOSE: verbose writes ... <long line text> ... and stuff.
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript End
End time: 20101105055855
**********************
```

Comment: You might perhaps want to also decorate the parameter to support pipelining `[Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true,         ValueFromPipeline=$true)]`