# powershell putting linebreaks inappropriate places in output

Tags: powershell, word-wrap, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell script, but some of the output gets cut at an arbitrary point before continuing on the next line. This is incredibly annoying.

For example, I can use `Write-Host` and the line will continue on as long as I want it (note, that is running in Team City and Team City adds some prefix information - however the same effect can be observed piping the output to a file):

```
[10:04:45] [Step 5/7]  - Found Windows Service at G:\TeamCityData\TeamCityBuildAgent-1\work\282b8abc9094651e\Artefacts\windows-services\WindowsService.Dummy\WindowsService.DummyService.exe
```

Other times, the output will seem to artificially truncate at an arbitrary point, like it was wrapping within a window (which isn't there).

So, this line:

```
Copy-Item -Path $fullSourcePath -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

Produces this output in Team City (which adds some prefix information):

```
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: 
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] G:\TeamCityData\TeamCityBuildAgent-1\work\282b8abc9094651e\Artefacts\windows-services\WindowsService.Dummy\WindowsServi
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] ce.DummyService.exe Destination: 
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] \\SERVER001\scheduled-tasks\ProductFolder\Dev\DummyWindowsService\WindowsService.DummyService.exe".
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: 
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] G:\TeamCityData\TeamCityBuildAgent-1\work\282b8abc9094651e\Artefacts\windows-services\WindowsService.Dummy\WindowsServi
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] ce.DummyService.exe.config Destination: 
[10:04:46] [Step 5/7] \\SERVER001\scheduled-tasks\ProductFolder\Dev\DummyWindowsService\WindowsService.DummyService.exe.config".
```

How do I stop this absurdity? I want the output to render line breaks correctly at the end of the line, not in the middle of a filename.

**UPDATE**

A comment below suggested this was an issue with the way TeamCity was capturing the output. However, the same issue happens if I do a similar command directly in a PowerShell console and pipe the output to a file.

The command:

```
copy-item -Path F:\logs -Destination .\ -Recurse -Verbose *> F:\logs\copy-item-output-1.txt
```

Produces output like this:

```
Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: F:\logs\20161103-140649-ProductName.Program.log 
Destination: F:\Destination\1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\this-is-a-long-path-name-to-show-wrapping-issues-with-copy-it
em\logs\20161103-140649-ProductName.Program.log".
```

As you can see, it also splits the file path across lines, even although it is being sent to a file, not the console window.

Comment: Looks like console host want to [wrap verbose output](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2017-01-06%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterface.cs#L1312) to the console window width, even if you not see that window.

Comment: TeamCity just pipes the output to Log4J and prepends the time and step. I get the same issue if I pipe the output to a file in powershell itself. So, it is not an issue with TeamCity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write-Verbose output that doesn't wrap to command width in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103484/write-verbose-output-that-doesnt-wrap-to-command-width-in-powershell)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because the verbose switch on `Copy-Item` does not appear to use `Write-Verbose`under the hood, so the change in that other SO answer does not work in this scenario.

Comment: `[System.Console]::BufferWidth=2000` works in pure Powershell, doesn't in ISE. For instance, `[System.Console]::BufferWidth=150` wraps `-verbose` output lines at every 150th character. Sorry, I have no knowledge about _TeamCity_.

Comment: Good point re TeamCity not being the culprit. Judging by @PetSerAl's link it looks like it's not just verbose output that's affected: All of the following PowerShell streams invariably word-wrap lines based on the console host interface's window width when outputting to the console, inexplicably even when the output is being redirected to a file: verbose, warning, debug. Please consider revising your question to take TeamCity out of the picture, so as to focus on the underlying, generic PowerShell behavior.

Comment: Team City does set a `MaxPhysicalWindowSize` for some reason, so it is still partially relevant to my specific issue, although not in the general. I'll update the question to make that tangential relationship clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution [(more than 10 years old so there might exist a smarter way recently?)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/12/04/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console/) works in both *PowerShell* and *PowerShell ISE*:

```
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
### do not change $newsize.height
$newsize.width = 3000               ### [int] type; max. value unknown at present
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
```

Comment: @mklement0 IMHO the window width does not matter as it's supposedly always _less than_ desired (huge) buffer width. Moreover, an attempt to **change the window width would fail in PS-ISE**. IAC, thanks for correcting my English.

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry, I can't verify this at all, being on Windows 8,1 and using PowerShell version 4.0 (and the question is tagged `4.0`).

Comment: ++. You are correct: setting the _buffer_ size is sufficient, as implied by the following line outputting `1`: `$rawUi = (Get-Host).ui.rawui; $bs = $rawUi.BufferSize; $bs.Width = $rawUi.WindowSize.Width+1; $rawUi.BufferSize = $bs; Write-Verbose -Verbose ('v' * ($rawUi.WindowSize.Width)) *> out; (Get-Content out).Count
`. I'm still baffled by the [current PS source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2017-01-06%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterface.cs#L1189) referencing `RawUI.WindowSize.Width`, i.e., the _window_ width, however.

Comment: (An aside re buffer width: it is typically the _same_ as the window width, so as to avoid the need for _horizontal_ scrolling; by contrast, it is the buffer _height_ that is typically much larger than the window height, to enable scrolling back vertically to previous output).

Comment: This is what I did in the end, changing the `windowsize.width` too.

Comment: I should also add, that when running through Team City it does have a `$pswindow.MaxPhysicalWindowSize` even although there is no window, so I set the width to be the width of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect other stream to output stream to provide custom handling for verbose and other types of output:

```
& {
    #Script code here
    Copy-Item -Path $fullSourcePath -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
} *>&1 | % {
    function IsStreamType {
        param($Object, $Type)
        $Property = $_.PSObject.Properties[$Type]
        $null -ne $Property -and $Property.Value -is [bool] -and $Property.Value
    }
} {
    switch(,$_) {
        {
            $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.DebugRecord] -and
            (IsStreamType $_ WriteDebugStream)
        } {
            "Debug message: $($_.Message)"
        }
        {
            $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord] -and
            (IsStreamType $_ WriteVerboseStream)
        } {
            "Verbose message: $($_.Message)"
        }
        {
            $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord] -and
            (IsStreamType $_ WriteWarningStream)
        } {
            "Warning message: $($_.Message)"
        }
        default { ,$_ }
    }
}
```

I use `,$_` instead of plain `$_` as precaution to prevent PowerShell unrolling behavior in case `$_` happens to be collection object.